# How to change a status of inprogress to completed of a student in Moodle v4

Tags: moodle

I have conducted an exam on moodle and add a timer in a quiz. The time is up and student does not click on submit and finish. Though all its data is there in review attempt but its status is in progress and I am not able to grade them.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have permission, you can manually complete an activity or a course for a student

For an activity go to Course admin menu > Reports > Activity completion

https://docs.moodle.org/402/en/Activity_completion_report

For a course go to Course admin menu > Reports > Course completion

https://docs.moodle.org/402/en/Course_completion_report

Comment: Is there a way to change the status using a bulk action?

Comment: Those reports will allow you to change completion for all students in a single course. Other than that, you will need custom development. There is a web service function that allows you to update the status `core_completion_override_activity_completion_status`  - see https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Web_service_API_functions